# Is there any performance difference in MySQL using default vs setting the value in the query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-optimization

I am wondering if its better to set default values for the table or set the in the values in the query performance-wise? Or is there any difference?

For example using default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for timestamp field. Versus no default and setting it in the INSERT INTO query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think default value could be faster, because when you send a query to database first it parses query and data to check if it fits to columns. Having more fields means more check, also it will check for proper timestamp value. But with default value, it checks and if everything is ok, just gets date time from system and continues.

By the way, this is so so small optimization... Maybe with some tests you can see how much difference they have.